# React - Apollo, how to put Object inside the query?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I'm working on Search functionality. On input change happen some stuff and I get array of arrays:

 `pages level 1 [1,17] 
 pages level 2 [15]
 pages level 3 [16]`

What I want is to create specific Object of pages from that array (this is not a problem) and put it to the Apollo query to be like this:

```
folders(search: [...some conditions]) {
data {
  id
  title

  pages(search: [{field: "id", value: "1"}, {field: "id", value: "17", type: OR}]) {
    data {
      id
      title
      pages(search: [{field: "id", value: "15"}]) {
        data {
          id
          title
          pages(search: [{field: "id", value: "16"}]) {
            data {
              id
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

And this is the place where I stuck! I can't use pure Apollo variables, because I don't know how deep this tree of pages can be, and also I think Apollo doesn't let me do some loop inside the query.

I think that I have to create this object inside my component, because there I can also save it to the Redux store.

I made something like that:

```
const thePages = SearchInTree.createQueryFragmentWithPages();
const ACCURATE_SEARCH_QUERY = gql`
  query SecondSearch{folders(search: [...some conditions]) {
    data {
      id
      title

      ${thePages}
    }
  }
}
```

where `thePages` - result of static method (where I'm going to create needed Object or a String) of my component class.  But in this case I've got another issue - Apollo doesn't want to see any changes inside my static, because query lies outside of my class.

Also I tried to take out this logic into separate component and there pull out the data from the Redux store. But than I don't know how to insert this component into my query.

I know that I missed something, maybe another way, I don't know...
Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue finally, by using withApollo HOC.
I give short instructions for newbies :)

```
import {compose, gql, withApollo} from 'react-apollo';
...// some imports

class TestClass extends React.Component {
    ...// some code

    let queryString = `folders{data{id, pages}}`;

    this.props.client.query({
      query: gql `query TestQuery{${queryString}}`,
      variables: someVar,

    }).then((data) => {
      console.log('then', data, this.props);
      // here you can also save result to the Redux store

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log('catch', err)
    });
}
...
export default withApollo(TestClass);
```

As you can see, it is possible to build some complex stuff and pass it to the query. Of course, you can wrap this query defining in a function and delegate it to some event, e.g. click.

Enjoy your coding ;)